# Passing values from C# to VBA code?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vba, excel, export-to-excel

I am pretty new to VBA, sorry if this is simple question or already answered... I tried by searching on MSDN but did not get any thing to implement this.

I am in need of sending a string (Host name in URL, e.g. xyzserver:4500/Home/GetExcelData) to VBA code before downloading the Excel to User.

I am calling MVC action method from Excel VBA code, getting some data and displaying in Excel.

My problem is Host name (xyzserver:4500) is different in different servers, I need to update the URL dynamically based on the server URL that the user is accessing from.

Basically i need to send server name to VBA code to update the URL in module. Is there any way to send and maintain values from  C# (MVC Action) to VBA?

Session/ Application Cache kind of things are available in VBA?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a parameter from c# to VBA in this manner:

```
Excel.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Open("your file here which contains the macro"); 
string url = "blah blah";
app.Run("name of macro here", url);
```

If you want to *edit* the vba code programmatically, then you would need to reference the VBIDE.  Have a look at Chip Pearson's excellent website: http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/vbe.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great resource. I will try and post updates of my problem here :)

Comment: Running excel macro from C# code is safe? Because, the same excel can be downloaded by multiple users at the same time. Since Excel is single threaded application, how it behaves when multiple users are running the same query (i mean downloading at the same time)?